# Mean of a truncated non-standard beta distribution

Tags: beta-distribution, truncated-distributions

I have a **non-standard beta distribution in the interval [-0.02 , 0.005]** (as opposed to [0,1]).

I know its mean and variance (and thus α and β).

I want to **calculate the mean of its truncation to [0 , 0.005]**.

See the following graph for clarification:

### [image: Truncate Non-standard Beta distribution for which I need to calculate the mean]

Is it possible to derive an equation for this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a special function called [the incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function), 
$$B(x;a,b)=\int_0^x t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}\text{d}t\qquad a,b>0$$
which serves both to normalise the density of a Beta $\mathcal{B}(a,b)$ distribution truncated to $(c,d)$:
$$f(x;a,b,c,d)=\dfrac{x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}}{B(d;a,b)-B(c,d)}$$
and to define its mean:
$$\mathbb{E}_{a,b,c,d}[X]=\dfrac{B(d;a+1,b)-B(c;a+1,b)}{B(d;a,b)-B(c,d)}$$

Comment: I see the Incomplete Beta Function requires a,b > 0 . My interval though is [-2%,0.5%]. Am I missing something?

Comment: I do not understand what an interval [-2%,0.5%] stands for.

Comment: Please excuse my lack of clarity. If you look at the X axis of my second graph, that is the interval my Beta distribution is defined around. Then it is truncated at 0. I still call it a Beta distribution since i) it has the exact same shape as the one above, and ii) I understand generalized Beta distributions work with negative intervals

Comment: I will reword the question for further clarification.

Comment: You have to defined which Beta distribution you want to truncate to $[-0.02,0.005]$ and it cannot be a standard Beta since those have support $(0,1)$. If you _truncate_ a distribution, the support of this distribution must be _larger_ than the truncation region.

Comment: My beta distribution goes from -0.02 to 0.005. The truncation is to 0 to 0.005, as shown in the graph. For the complete one (-0.02, 0.005), I have the mean and the variance.