# Bayesian Estimation of Donut Lovers

Tags: bayesian

I posted this question [Bayesian Probabilities for Estimating the Percentage of Donut Lovers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637799/bayesian-probabilities-for-estimating-the-percentage-of-donut-lovers) and it got closed. I thought maybe I could simplify the question (this is the first Bayesian problem I have ever worked on start to finish):

- Suppose 2020, there are 100 people: 75 in Group A ($N_{A,2020}$) and 25 in Group B ($N_{B,2020}$).
- 83% of people in Group A like donuts ($ p_{A,2020}$), but we don't know what percent of people in Group B like donuts ($p_{B,2020}$). However, we think that it is unlikely that more than 83% of people in Group B like donuts.
- In 2021, there is a brand new population (i.e. no one from 2020) of 150 people (that we believe might have similar donut preferences as the 2020 population). However, we don't know what percent of the 2021 population will be in Group A and what percent will be in Group B.
- Problem: **Can we estimate the total percent of people in 2021 that might like donuts?**
- To make the problem simpler, I am assuming independence between population ratios and donut preferences

**Part 1: Prior Distributions and Likelihoods**

- **Likelihood for Group A Donut Lovers (Binomial)**:

$$
P(D_{A,2020} | p_{A,2020}, N_{A,2020}) = \binom{N_{A,2020}}{D_{A,2020}} p_{A,2020}^{D_{A,2020}} (1-p_{A,2020})^{N_{A,2020}-D_{A,2020}}
$$

- **Prior for Group A Donut Lovers (Beta)**:

$$ P(p_{A,2020}) \sim Beta(\alpha_{A,2020}, \beta_{A,2020}) = \frac{p_{A,2020}^{\alpha_{A,2020}-1} (1-p_{A,2020})^{\beta_{A,2020}-1}}{B(\alpha_{A,2020}, \beta_{A,2020})}$$

- **Problem : There is no Likelihood for Group B Donut Lovers (by definition) - we can only assume some value of value of $p_{B,2020}$, ideally less than than $p_{A,2020}$ with a  "wider" Prior. Is this a problem?**
- **Prior for Group B Donut Lovers (Beta)**: I am not sure how to write this such that the Prior respects the 0.83 constraint (truncated/incomplete Beta [Mean of a truncated non-standard beta distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/391031/mean-of-a-truncated-non-standard-beta-distribution?)). I think the parameters of this Beta prior should be chosen in a way such that the prior becomes "wider" to capture the fact that we are less confident about Group B donut preferences compared to Group A?

$$ P(p_{B,2020}) \sim Beta(\alpha_{B,2020}, \beta_{B,2020}) = \frac{p_{B,2020}^{\alpha_{B,2020}-1} (1-p_{B,2020})^{\beta_{B,2020}-1}}{B(\alpha_{B, 2020}, \beta_{B,2020})}$$

- **Likelihood for the Ratio Counts (Multinomial) :**

$$
P(N_{A,2020}, N_{B,2020} | x_{A,2020}, x_{B,2020}) \propto x_{A,2020}^{N_{A,2020}} x_{B,2020}^{N_{B,2020}}
$$

- **Prior for the Ratio (Dirichlet):**

$$
P(x_{A,2020}, x_{B,2020}) = \frac{1}{B(3, 1)} N_{A,2020}^{2}
$$

**Part 2: Posterior Distributions**

$$
P(p_{A,2020} | D_{A,2020}, N_{A,2020}) \sim Beta(\alpha_{A,2020} + D_{A,2020}, \beta_{A,2020} + N_{A,2020} - D_{A,2020})
$$

$$
P(p_{B,2020} | D_{B,2020}, N_{B,2020}) \sim Beta(\alpha_{B,2020} + D_{B,2020}, \beta_{B,2020} + N_{B,2020} - D_{B,2020})
$$

$$
P(N_{A,2020}, N_{B,2020} | N_{A,2020}, N_{B,2020}) \sim Dirichlet(N_{A,2020} + 2, N_{B,2020})
$$

Thus, if you know the total number of people in 2021 - via the Posterior MAP's, we can estimate the expected ratio of people in A:B ... and then estimate the percent of A that will like donuts and estimate the percent of B that will like donuts.

I am feeling a bit lost here and I think I have approached this problem in the wrong way. Can someone please guide me on how I can salvage my analysis?

Comment: can someone please give me some feedback here on how I should ask this question?

Comment: Hi! I didn't vote to close your question, but in any case discussing that in the comment section can become complicated due to the character limitation. If you want, you can ask for feedback about your question on the meta website (https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/, note the "meta" in the web address).

Comment: thanks ... it seems this one also got closed ... do you have any ideas how to solve this question?